# Sprite Node leaving frame

Tags: sprite-kit

I've set the physics body for both the background and the other sprite node, yet the node can still leave the the border. It doesn't fall through the bottom, it can leave on the sides though.

```
SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg"];
bg.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2,   self.scene.size.height/2);
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
[self addChild:bg];

SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*.5, 200);
player.name = @"player";
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];
player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = barCategory;
[self addChild:player];
```

What i think is happening is the body of the the background node is wider than what the view is showing. How can i make it so that the body dimension is what ever the view is.

Comment: Where in your code is the code you are showing? Is it in the initWithSize of the SKScene?

Comment: Your player node's physics body is probably smaller than the actual image size.

Comment: @rakeshbs Isn't that what self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame]; does?

Comment: are you using an sks file?

Comment: @rakeshbs this is in a .m file

Comment: no. i was not asking about that. check your gameviewcontroller and check the place where GameScene is initialised. is it `GameScene.unarchiveFromFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the initialisation line of `GameScene` in `GameViewController` to

```
GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc]
                    initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height)];
```